# Why can't i access the value in the global variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the below code I am using ajax to obtain all data from the database and store it in the proj4_data variable. The variable is global. I am able to access the value of the variable when I click on a  button on the page, but when I try to access the variable value right after callback function is done loading, the value of the variable is empty (the alert is where I try to get the value).
 Can someone help tell why this is happening:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
    var prod_name =  document.getElementById('product_name');

    cart = new shopping_cart("jadrn026");

    proj4_data = new Array();
    $.get('/perl/jadrn000/proj4/get_products.cgi', storeData);
alert(proj4_data);
    $('#milk').on('click', function() {
    tmpString = "";

    var value = $("#milk").val();
    prod_name.innerHTML = value;
        tmpString += '<ul id="db_items">';
    for(var i=0; i < proj4_data.length; i++) {

        if(proj4_data[i][1] == "Milk chocolate") {
        var str1 = proj4_data[i][2].split("'").join("\\'");
        var str2 = proj4_data[i][3].split("'").join("\\'");
        var str3 = proj4_data[i][4].split("'").join("\\'");

        tmpString += "<li><button class=\"description\" onclick=\"showDesc(\'" + str1 + "\', \'" + str2 + "\', \'" + str3 +  "\', \'" + proj4_data[i][0] + "\', \'" + proj4_data[i][6] + "\')\"><img src=\"/~jadrn000/PROJ4_IMAGES/" + proj4_data[i][0]+".jpg\" alt=\""+ proj4_data[i][2]+"\""+
            " width=\"200px\"  /></button><br />";  
        tmpString += "<p id='price'>$" + proj4_data[i][6] + "</p>";
        tmpString += "<input type='button' value='Order' onclick=\"showDesc(\'" + str1 + "\', \'" + str2 + "\', \'" + str3 +  "\', \'" + proj4_data[i][0] + "\', \'" + proj4_data[i][6] + "\')\"" + proj4_data[i][0]+"' />";
        }
    }
    tmpString += "</ul>";
    var handle = document.getElementById('content');
    handle.innerHTML = tmpString;

    });
    function storeData(response) {
    var tmpArray = explodeArray(response,';');
    for(var i=0; i < tmpArray.length; i++) {
        innerArray = explodeArray(tmpArray[i],'|');
        proj4_data[i] = innerArray;
        }

    }


    // from http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/3262.htm            
    function explodeArray(item,delimiter) {
    tempArray=new Array(1);
    var Count=0;
    var tempString=new String(item);

    while (tempString.indexOf(delimiter)>0) {
    tempArray[Count]=tempString.substr(0,tempString.indexOf(delimiter));
    tempString=tempString.substr(tempString.indexOf(delimiter)+1,tempString.length-tempString.indexOf(delimiter)+1);
    Count=Count+1
    }

    tempArray[Count]=tempString;
    return tempArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rest of your code doesn't stop while it waits for the AJAX request to complete. It sends the request and then immediately executes the alert. Since the request hasn't completed yet, the variable is still empty.

If you want to run the alert after the request, put the alert in the callback function.

Comment: Oh ok got it. Yes I tried the alert in the callback and that worked. Thank you.Also just wanted to know whether it is possible to access this variable in another javascript file without having to rewrite the code for callback function. I defined both files in my html in the right order.